# 403 Forbidden - Permission - VHOSTS

Tags: apache, virtual, host, http-status-code-403, vhosts

I couldn't access no more my vhosts (only the default one, localhost). It makes me :

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I already load the module in my httpd.conf, I'm on apache 2.4, and I already check all the permissions folders (chmod 755).

My httpd-vhosts.conf file :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/POlo/Sites/polohome"
    ServerName polohome
    # Set access permission
    <Directory "/Users/POlo/Sites/polohome">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/POlo/Sites/aeglos"
        ServerName aeglos
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/aeglos.local-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/aeglos.local-access_log" common

        <Directory "/Users/POlo/Sites/aeglos/">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The only thing I've found is when changing the DirectoryIndex in the httpd.conf file, it render me a php line without executing it.. And adding the directoryIndex on the httpd-vhosts.conf file did nothing.

Thanks for help.

UPDATE : Don't understand why.. But it's working when switching to PHP 5.6, on php 7.0.6 still rendering me 403 forbidden page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

After upgrading my mac, my php switcher wasn't working cause by the php7_module which wasn't called in the httpd.conf.